# Plugging a newline at the end of a newline with a null character?

Tags: c

I have the following code written which is allocating an array of 1000 pointers to characters strings and then each character string is read from stdin and the strdup each line into the array.

Im not sure how to plug the newline at the end of each line with a ’\0’, but not error out if there is no newline?? Can someone please explain?

```
char *array[1000];
char buffer[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      int reading = scanf("%s", buffer);
      array[i] = strdup(buffer);

      // If EOF is detected, stop
      if (reading == EOF) {
         break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at answers of your previous question.

Comment: `scanf("%s", buffer)` does not read a line of input, only a continuous sequence of non-white space.

Comment: I apologize for putting this up as second post.